# Hover not working on the styled component

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I expected to make left and right arrows visible when I hover over the Wrapper component. But nothing happens.
Does it have anything with the re-rendering of component.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import p1 from "../images/slider-badag.jpg";
import p2 from "../images/slider-badging.jpg";
import p3 from "../images/slider-scale.jpg";
import p4 from "../images/slider-scales.jpg";

const ImgSlider = () => {
  const imgArr = [p1, p2, p3, p4];
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    const id = setInterval(() => {
      if (index < imgArr.length - 1) {
        setIndex(index + 1);
      } else setIndex(0);
    }, 3000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(id);
    };
  }, [index]);
  return (
    <>
      <Wrapper imgUrl={imgArr[index]}>
        <LeftArrow>
          <div className="left-icon-wrapper">
            <i className="arrowl left"></i>
          </div>
        </LeftArrow>
        <RightArrow>
          <div className="right-icon-wrapper">
            <i className="arrowr right"></i>
          </div>
        </RightArrow>
      </Wrapper>
    </>
  );
};
const LeftArrow = styled.div`
  .arrowl {
    border: solid white;
    border-width: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .left {
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  }
  .left-icon-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    top: 20vh;
    left: -2vw;
    opacity: 0;
  }

`;
const RightArrow = styled.div`
  .arrowr {
    border: solid white;
    border-width: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .right {
     transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  .right-icon-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    left: 90vw;
    top: 20vh;
    opacity: 0;
  }
`;
const Wrapper = styled.div`
  transition: background-image 0.5s ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: .7em;
  height: calc(160% / 3.3);
  background-image: url(${(props) => props.imgUrl});
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: -1;
  &:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    ${LeftArrow} {
      .left-icon-wrapper{
      opacity: 1 !important;
      }
    }
    ${RightArrow} {
      .right-icon-wrapper{
      opacity: 1 !important;
      }
    }
  }
`;

export default ImgSlider;
```

I was trying to make LeftArrow and RightArrow component visible when hovering over Wrapper element. But nothing happens. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You are not hitting the exact class on which the default `opacity` is `0`
try this at the place of wrapper

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
 transition: background-image 0.5s ease-in-out;
 position: relative;
 border: 1px solid transparent;
 border-radius: .7em;
 height: calc(160% / 3.3);
 background-image: url(${(props) => props.imgUrl});
 background-size: 100%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 z-index: -1;
&:hover {
cursor: pointer;
${LeftArrow} {
  .left-icon-wrapper {
    opacity: 1 !important;
  }
}
${RightArrow}{
  .right-icon-wrapper {
    opacity: 1 !important;
  }    
 }

}`;
```

And one more thing, Be careful with the `position=absolute` on arrow clases

Comment: Thanks, tried but it didn't work.

Comment: Please remove the z-index: -1; from Wrapper and check again.

Comment: Yes it worked actually there was a container component which wrapped the ImgSlider component like <Container><ImgSlider/></Container> and z-index of container component was also equal to -1. On removing that z-index it worked.Thanks for your insight.

Answer (score -1):

The use of `id` selectors will override the nested hover rules because of [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

That means even though you have given it `opacity: 1` it will resolve to `0` because the ID selectors `#right` and `#left` take precedence.

Get rid of the IDs and just use class names, which have weaker specificity than ID selectors.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import p1 from "../images/slider-badag.jpg";
import p2 from "../images/slider-badging.jpg";
import p3 from "../images/slider-scale.jpg";
import p4 from "../images/slider-scales.jpg";

const ImgSlider = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Wrapper imgUrl={imgArr[index]}>
        <LeftArrow>
          <div className="left-icon-wrapper">
            <i className="arrowl left"></i>
          </div>
        </LeftArrow>
        <RightArrow id="r">
          <div className="right-icon-wrapper" onClick={handleClick}>
            <i className="arrowr right"></i>
          </div>
        </RightArrow>
      </Wrapper>
    </>
  );
};
const LeftArrow = styled.div`
  .arrowl {
    border: solid white;
    border-width: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .left {
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  }
  .left-icon-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    top: 20vh;
    left: -2vw;
    opacity: 0;
  }

`;
const RightArrow = styled.div`
  .arrowr {
    border: solid white;
    border-width: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .right {
     transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  .right-icon-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    left: 90vw;
    top: 20vh;
    opacity: 0;
  }
`;
const Wrapper = styled.div`
  transition: background-image 0.5s ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: .7em;
  height: calc(160% / 3.3);
  background-image: url(${(props) => props.imgUrl});
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: -1;
  &:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    ${LeftArrow} .left-icon-wrapper {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    ${RightArrow} .right-icon-wrapper{
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
`;

export default ImgSlider;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But after using className instead of id as you suggested its still not working.

Comment: I forgot to add the targetting to the icon wrappers in the hover rules. Try now.

Comment: yeah I tried but still not working even the mouse pointer does not become "pointer" as desired.

Comment: I edited the post to include full code do take a look please.